# Simultaneous NSURLConnection from within prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a UITableView that requests for more data from the server when the user hits the bottom of the table (similar to the Twitter application). However, I'm trying to use a modal segue to filter out data to the user's desire. In order to properly select which data to filter, I have to load ALL of the data to categorize it. In order to load everything, I am required to send out multiple NSURLConnections to load multiple pages. I am trying to have it so when one completes, the next one starts.

However since the connection completes with `connectionDidFinishLoading`, I have not figured out a way to send out simultaneous NSURLConnections from within `prepareForSegue`. I tried using a while loop in `prepareForSegue` as follows:

```
while (All of the data is not loaded) {
    if (isLoading == NO) {
        [self loadMoreResults];
    }
}
```

where "isLoading" is a `BOOL` declared in my viewcontroller's implementation file. isLoading changes value to YES inside `loadMoreResults`, and changes back to `NO` at the end of `connectionDidFinishLoading`. However, within `prepareForSegue`, isLoading never changes back from YES to NO.

Is this a multithreading issue? I have done research on other questions and see that NSURLConnection has a class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` where the completion handler might help, but I'm unsure how I would use it.

ALSO: I want to continue executing `prepareForSegue` AFTER the last connection finishes, not right after it sends the request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Then you should not link the segue directly from the bar button item to the view controller in the storyboard.

Just link a general segue with identifier from the table view controller to the filter view controller.

And from the bar button item, create an action for it from the storyboard so that you can send out multiple NSURLConnections first.

Finally then in your code, after the last connection finishes, call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

Comment: I actually have the segue connection to a Bar Button in the UINavigation bar, and not the UITableViewCell. Is there a way to call a method (prior to prepareForSegue) once the user taps the Bar Button?

Comment: @AUSTOOO Updated my answer. There is no way to stop the segue first if you link it directly to the bar button in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the segue part! Any chance you know how send another request from the action method once `connectionDidFinishLoading` completes?

Comment: @AUSTOOO What do you mean by sending another request? Create a new NSURLConnection in the connectionDidFinishLoading? Is this a different issue?

Comment: My question was sort of a two part question. I am sending out all the NSURLConnections from the action method I just created. Once `connectionDidFinishLoading` completes, I need to know how to send out another NSURLConnection from the action method. I tried doing this with a BOOL property defined in the class (isLoading) but the value does not update, which (i think but may be wrong) is due to `connectionDidFinishLoading` being ran in a separate thread than the action method.